# Cos'è "un saccone di cartocci" riferito a un letto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Un matrimonio in provincia* della Marchesa Colombi (pseudonimo di Maria Antonietta Torriani) ho letto:

> I nostri letti erano di quelli primitivi, fatti di cavalletti e panchette, 
>   con **un saccone di cartocci** ed una materassa.

Non capisco il significato di "cartoccio" in questa frase. Ho cercato questo vocabolo in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire cosa possa essere riferito a un letto. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il *cartoccio* è anche il gruppo di foglie (brattee) che copre una pannocchia di granoturco ([accezione **3** del Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cartoccio/)). 
Era uno dei materiali poveri che si usavano per imbottiture ecc.
I dizionari spesso lo danno come significato ma non lo connettono all'uso che se ne faceva a meno che non cerchi la parola *pagliericcio*.

Se ti va, una lettura giusto per informazione: [Materassi e sacconi](http://www.carraraonline.com/racconti/materassi_e_sacconi.html).

Immagina un letto così, con un'imbottita non molto diversa dal materasso stesso (alla "tedesca" dove, se non si è abituati, ti viene da dire che si sono dimenticati di mettere lenzuola e coperte sul tuo letto):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In questa frase è probabile che "saccone di cartocci" voglia dire che la coperta con il quale si coprivano era niente di più di un "sacco" pieno di carta / cartone. Notoriamente questo tipo di materiale tiene caldo (basti pensare che è molto usato da chi vive per strada come imbottitura dei vestiti durante la notte) ed essendo inoltre un materiale "povero" rientra nel contesto.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!